# shell script calling another script but changes not in effect

Tags: shell-script

I have a script which is a basic loop that runs indefinitely; it calls another script and then sleeps for 30 seconds. I made changes to the inner script but they are not always taking effect in the next loop of the outer script. Do shells like bash cache the inner script? I structured it like this so I can make changes to the inner script without having to restart the outer script.

Comment: Please, isolate a minimum shell script able to reproduce the issue you experience and show us the code by editing your post. Please read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327703/how-to-cache-a-variable-used-inside-a-bash-completion-script-for-the-current-ses)

As far as whether or not Bash caches variables, it seems like the answer is, if you want it to, just according to this Q&A.

I hope that helps.